# How to get responses from google assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

We have built a custom agent using google dialog flow with limited intents. When ever the dialog flow agent identifies the question as fallback intent we would like to pass the question to google assistant and wanted to get the response from google assistant. I have tried enabling google assistant in case of fallback intent even that did not work. Any help on how to get responses from google assistant is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't, and you probably don't want to.

In theory, you could make a webhook and set your fallback intent to use this webhook for fulfillment. This webhook would use the Assistant SDK to send the text to the Assistant and relay the response.

In practice, this would be a bad idea for a number of reasons:

- Users are using your action because they are attempting to do something that your action should do. If your action doesn't do it, they aren't likely to use it in the first place.
- Things captured by the Fallback Intent aren't always the user trying to do something else. They may just be misunderstood questions from the user that you didn't setup a matching sample phrase for. You need to assume your users are trying to work with you, rather than replying with something outside you.
- It can introduce fairly large latency, which leads to a very negative experience for your users. Depending how you have implemented this, over time, this can lead to significant costs for you.

You may wish to catch specific phrases from the user. For example, if they say "hey Google" or "ok Google", you may want to remind them that they're still using your Action rather than Google. Or you may wish to thank them and close your Action.

Comment: Thanks prisoner. But how can I made my bot to handle generic questions(like whether related, traffic related etc)? Is there any alternative way to handle this?

Comment: You're just repeating your question. Was there part of my answer that was unclear that I can explain better?

Answer (score 0):

as per my knowledge as of now google assistants feedback can't be invoked directly into the model as it only flows our own follow-ups and fx. though if we can design another model which totally functions with google's assistant then it is possible, in that scenario calling the new intent through webhook is possible.